# Site analytics: "all posts" and "questions" show the same data

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-analytics

Here's a screen capture from a site where I can view `/site-analytics`:

[image: broken plot]

The orange "all posts" curve should be strictly larger than the blue "questions" curve, but they are mistakenly displaying the same data.

Comment: Yup... I see this here on MSE, too. Wonder what happened there.

Comment: A guess: an SQL typo which left a `where PostType = "question"` in the wrong place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now fixed. The root cause was something like this:

```
AllPostsDatapoints.Add( questionDatapoint?.Value ?? 0 + answerDatapoint?.Value ?? 0 )
```

The intent here is to sum the question and answer counts for a given date, allowing for the possibility that either or both might be null (no questions or answers for that day). But... [The null coalescing operator has lower precedence than the addition operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511093/what-is-the-operator-precedence-of-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator), so what the expression *actually* evaluates to is... The question count, unless there were no questions, in which case it evaluates to the answer count.

I'm not normally a big fan of junking up expressions with lots of parentheses, but in this case that's the only way it really works:

```
AllPostsDatapoints.Add( (questionDatapoint?.Value ?? 0) + (answerDatapoint?.Value ?? 0) )
```

Thanks for reporting this!